# Query has no destination in a plpgsql function?

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have this function and its giving an error:

> ```
> query has no destination for result data
> ```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "alarmEventList"(sampleid integer
                            , starttime timestamp without time zone
                            , stoptime timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$BEGIN
select array_agg(result::text) 
from (
    select to_char("Timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    ,"AlertLevel"
    ,"Timestamp" - lag("Timestamp") over (order by "Timestamp")
           from "Judgements" 
           WHERE "SampleID" = sampleid
           and "Timestamp" >= starttime 
           and "Timestamp" <= stoptime
         ) result 
    where "AlertLevel" > 0;
return result;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

After I try to run this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alarm_event_list(sampleid integer
                           , starttime timestamp without time zone
                           , stoptime timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS text[] AS $$
 select array_agg(result::text) 
from (
    select to_char("Timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    ,"AlertLevel"
    ,"Timestamp" - lag("Timestamp") over (order by "Timestamp")
           from "Judgements" 
           WHERE "SampleID" = sampleid
           and "Timestamp" >= starttime 
           and "Timestamp" <= stoptime
         ) result 
    where "AlertLevel" > 0;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

gives me an error saying "sampleid" does not exist even though is just a declare parameter.
I don't know why since I'm placing everything in the result.

Comment: Where are you placing it in the result? BTW this function seems simple enough not to require plpgsql, see [Query Language (SQL) Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html).

Comment: i want to return an array, how would it be in sql ? i'm new to databases

Comment: Did you try it? Did you read the docs I linked?

Comment: Postgres version? Before [v9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-2.html#AEN116858) the SQL function arguments could only be referenced as numbers - $1 being the first argument etc.

Comment: yeah, i used $1... and it worked thanks, i just don't see the function in my list of functions is that because i used sql instead of plpgsql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result of any embedded query should be saved to some result (or you have to use a PERFORM statement) in plpgsql language.

you can write a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(..)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE result text[];
BEGIN
  result := (SELECT array_agg(...) FROM sometable);
  RETURN result;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(..)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE result text[];
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO result array_agg(...) FROM sometable;
  RETURN result;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: is there any way i can format the result, right now i get something like this:{"(\"2013-10-16 15:10:40\",1,)","(\"2013-10-16 15:11:52\",1,00:00:48)"}, can i formatted to get something like this: 2013-10-16 15:10:40,1,,2013-10-16 15:11:52,1,00:00:48 ??

Comment: @UbaldoQuintero: Please start a *new question* for a new question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens No, you should not use a RETURN QUERY, when you returns one value. RETURN QUERY should be used inside table returning functions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I would simplify the function with an [**`OUT` parameter**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(.., OUT result text[]) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO result array_agg(...) FROM sometable;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This way, the OUT parameter defines the return type as well as the variable to hold the result from the query.
You can skip the `RETURNS` clause, the `DECLARE` section and the variable declaration as well as the `RETURN` statement. The function does the same.

You could also just use an **SQL function**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(..)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg(...) AS result FROM sometable;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```